# Reading, converting Object Array

Tags: python, bluetooth, bluez

I am trying to compile  :

```
new_value = int(1500).to_bytes(2, byteorder='little')
```

but it throws error in Python 3.5 and 3.8.

I am new in python and couldn't find an explanation on this. And also how to read a data from object array

Comment: Your question would be better if it had the exact versions of python and the error message from those version. Can you give an example of the object array you want to read?

Comment: @ukBaz i knew how to do the cast & conversion but as i can see, it stores in object array. What if i want to read say `(btn.ReadValue({}))` which i want to read the byte only,say 1 or 0? Currently i am reading the change via `value = prop_changed.get('Value', None)`

Comment: Is your question, how to convert [0] -> 0 and [1] -> 1?

Comment: `int.from_bytes(value, byteorder="little")`

Comment: This isn't working on python 3.5 or 3.8.Do i need to import? Thank you :)

Comment: It is working fine on my machine on Python 3.8
```
Python 3.8.4 (tags/v3.8.4:dfa645a, Jul 13 2020, 16:30:28) [MSC v.1926 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> value = [0]
>>> int.from_bytes(value, byteorder='little')
0
>>> value = 0
>>> value.to_bytes(1, byteorder='little')
b'\x00'
```

Comment: Thanks ukBaz . The problem is mine on Raspberry Pi. I tried to upgrade the current python3.5 but unable to do so.